# How to Bind Model with variable at Runtime in mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model having more than 50 fields and I want to display list of those fields **but not all of them**.

So I have created two viewbag having list of display field and all values.

Now I have,

```
<table>
<tr>
   @foreach (var v in @ViewBag.columnList)
   {
       <th>@v</th>
   }
</tr>

        @foreach (var u in  @ViewBag.userlist)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var c in @ViewBag.columnList)
                {

                    <td>@u.c</td>
                }
            </tr>
    }
```

I want to assign `@u.@c` to select column to display in table.

Comment: use a ViewModel which only has the data you need. You can then use `@Html` helpers for displaying. It sounds like you are exposing a domain model and probably leaving yourself open to a mass assignment attack.

Comment: I want to display only those field which is in the columnList.How?

Comment: I don't think you can do it like this, can you give more info on what you are trying to achieve because it looks like a bad design anyway. Show the Models and explain the requirement

Comment: ViewBag.columnList is the selected column list which is dynamic. It may have all column name or selected column name from ViewBag.columnList and ViewBag.userlist have complete info about user that is lots of column (larger than 40). I only want to select only those column from ViewBag.columnList and display. If I would have passed model of userList, then i should have write `@foreach(var v in Model){@v.Name @v.address}`. But here those values are in ViewBag.columnList. So I want to assign those values in @v.viewbag.columnlist, RUNTIME. Is it Possible??

Comment: No. For the sake of anyone who one day would need to support your app, gladly, no.

Comment: Ok. Then Let me Ask this question in another way. I have a model called UserDetails having name, address, state, etc. Now admin has selected that name and state of the user should display in userlist. Again it is not restricted that admin will only select name and state. now I have passed model from controller in list of all details. At run time I have to show only those column which was selected by admin. how will I implement this? Please help???

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class UserBaseModel
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string City {get;set;}
}

public class UserModel : UserBaseModel
{
   public string State {get;set;}
}

public class AdminModel : UserBaseModel
{
   public string Gender {get;set;}
}
```

These classes show the different user types having different Properties. You could then have a view stongly typed with the base class

```
@model UserBaseModel
```

This way you can pass different models to the view depending on the user. You then have a choice how to access those Properties. It *might* allow you to select out the Property even though there won't be intelisense, I haven't tried.

You could also have partial views for user type, then depending on type of user in questions, load the relevant partial. Point being, you can pass either User to Admin to the view in the example and both will work.

Comment: I only have to display list of selected column. and the column list is variable.